# Is there any way to migrate data from CloudKit?

Tags: ios, icloud, cloudkit

I'd like to build a simple iOS only app that's going to be social. I don't yet have a way to monetize this app, so I'd like to keep this project as cheap as possible. Since it's iOS only, I figured I would use CloudKit because of its very generous free tier. However, if I ever decided to make this a cross platform app, would I be able to migrate my user data somewhere else?

Comment: I have the same question. Did you figure out an answer?

Comment: @user1563544 I'll probably use cloudkit and put all my data in public, then use CloudKit JS in a Node.js app to move the data. The only downside is that I'll have to break CloudKit for older versions of the app. Not ideal.

Answer (score 1):

As of December 2019, there is no simple way to migrate data from CloudKit. The data stored in each user's private data base is not accessible by the developer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use CloudKit with Android because of the CloudKit JS implementation. The real problem is, that I think that also the android user needs an iCloud Account do something with that.

So maybe the better way is to use google firebase.

https://firebase.google.com

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all. Can data be migrated from CloudKit?

Comment: As you stated, it would require an iCloud account. That would be weird and clunky for Android users. Also, without a way to monetize my app Firebase would get expensive quickly.

Answer (score 0):

There is always the option to do this inside of the app for each individual user. If the data is not too large and complicated it should be easily done.
But make sure to inform the user and give them a choice to move or don't move the data. Let both services run for some time parallel before removing the cloudkit option for old users completely. Obviously moving data using the app can cause certain issues if the move doesn't go as planned.